# Run time error 9 on for loop for no reason

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, time

I am trying to run the loop circled in red that gives me the “mm” according to the “mmm”. For example if I had “Jun” I would get a “06” in return. Nothing fancy at all. I try running this code with proper range “1 To 12” and I always get “Run-time error ‘9’: Subscript out of range”, so I tried lowering the range to “1 To 11”. When I do this I get no error I get no error, but I also get no result. Nothing happens!

If you look at the watches when I get the error I actually get the answers I need, but  it’s just that the error keeps me from getting anywhere with those answers. Is there something I am missing? Why is this happening. Should I just find a way to suppress the run time error if I can?

I've triple checked the size of my arrays and they are both 12.

```
Option Explicit
    Dim mmmonth() As Variant
    Dim MM() As Variant
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim thismo As String
    Dim thismon As String
Sub Shift1JuneReportMonthly()

        thismon = Mid(fileno, 5, 3)
        mmmonth = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
        MM = Array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12")

        For ii = 1 To 12
            If mmmonth(ii) = thismon Then
                thismo = MM(ii)
            End If
        Next ii
End Sub
```

In my watches, even though there's an error I see the expected correct results in my Watches: mmmonth(ii)=12, and thismo ="06". When I make the index 1 To 11 though, the code doesn't throw up an error, but all the watches just say "".

Comment: Try `For ii = 0 To 11`

Comment: Not sure what `fileno` equals to, but if it's a `String` in any recognizable date format, you can use `thismo = Month(DateValue(fileno))`

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad , I have tried ii = 0 to 11. The error goes away, but the code does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer is basically in the comments (0 being LBound for your array), I think you can drastically improve your code with the following:

```
Option Explicit

Dim thismo As String

Sub Shift1JuneReportMonthly()
    thismo = Month(DateValue("01-" & Mid(fileno, 5, 3) & "-2019"))
End Sub
```

I assume `fileno` is a cell you refer to? Not sure if you want to keep `thismo as string` or make it a `Long` variable isntead.

Comment: Thank you so much @JvdV , fileno is the file name, that eliminates the need for the loop right there. I appreciate it.